# Fit state space model using dlm

Tags: r

I am about to fit a state space model to at univariate time series (y_t). The model i try to fit is:

```
y_t=F x_t+\epsilon_t, \epsilon_t \sim N(0,V)
x_{t+1}=G x_t+w_t, w_t \sim N(0,W)
x_0 \sim N(m_0,C_0)
```

I use the following R-code:

```
# Create function of unknown parameters, which returns dlm object
Build <- function(theta) {dlm(FF=theta[1],
GG=theta[2],V=theta[3],W=theta[4],m0=theta[5],
C0=theta[6])}

# Fit model to data using MLE
f1 <- dlmMLE(y,parm=c(1,1,0.1,0.1,0,0.1),Build)
```

But I get the following error message (after running f1):

```
Error in dlm(FF = theta[1], GG = theta[2], V = theta[3], W = theta       [4],  : 
V is not a valid variance matrix
```

My problem is that I don't understand why V is not a valid variance matrix..

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thank you in advance

Regards fuente

EDIT:

I tried doing the same, but instead of my real data I used:

```
y <- rnorm(72,6.44,1.97)
```

This produced, however, an error involving W (and not V...):

```
Error in dlm(FF = theta[1], GG = theta[2], V = theta[3], W = theta[4],  :
```

W is not a valid variance matrix

I'm confused. Does it have something to do with the starting values passed to parm=...?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, of course. Use as y the vector rnorm(72,6.44,1.97)

Comment: I just edited the original post a bit...

Comment: I suppose that your code is normally used for multivariate model and you are trying to apply it to a univariate time series, thats why the function is expecting that `W` is a covariance matrix

Comment: Yeah, that sounds plausible. I'll try out another package. Thanks.